# 401 Unauthorized error while logging into Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I am trying to log into Tomcat 9.0.38 for Windows 10 (apache-tomcat-9.0.38.exe).
I get error:

```
401 Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page. If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the file conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation. That file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp
```

.

Comment: Can you provide any more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 10 US/English, but with codepage UTF-8 for console applications:
[how to set UTF-8 codepage for console applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we0t4.png)

```
C:\Tomcat\conf>chcp
Active code page: 65001
```

So during installation apache-tomcat-9.0.38.exe generated C:\Tomcat\conf\tomcat-users.xml with correct encoding from its own opinion:
[encoding in compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBcfK.png)

So file C:\Tomcat\conf\tomcat-users.xml with encoding encoding='cp65001' is loaded without any warnings, but values are not initiated.

Changing encoding of tomcat-users.xml into utf-8 allows to fix the issue with user logging into Tomcat.